# Terraform: JSON Path Query doesn't work in terraform

Tags: json, path, terraform

I have data like below in json file site24x7IPs.json, and new filter it in terraform:

```
{
    "LocationDetails": [
        {
            "IPv6_Address_External": "2803:eb80:4000:d::0/64",
            "City": "Buenos Aires",
            "Place": "Argentina",
            "external_ip": "170.78.75.88"
        },
        {
            "IPv6_Address_External": "",
            "City": "Buenos Aires",
            "Place": "Argentina",
            "external_ip": "170.78.75.87"
        },
        {
            "IPv6_Address_External": "",
            "City": "Melbourne",
            "Place": "Australia",
            "external_ip": "103.91.166.0/24"
        }
    ]
}
```

And terraform code:

```
locals {
  site24x7IPs = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/site24x7IPs.json"))
}

output "site24x7IPs" {
  #value = local.site24x7IPs.LocationDetails[*].external_ip        # This works

  # I'd like to filter the IP from Australia, 
  value = local.site24x7IPs.LocationDetails[?(@.Place == "Australia")].external_ip
}
```

Expecting Result:

```
"103.91.166.0/24"
```

Output:

```
value = local.site24x7IPs.LocationDetails[?(@.Place == "Australia")].external_ip

This character is not used within the language.
```

.LocationDetails[?(@.Place == "Australia")].external_ip is the JSON query syntax, but it doesn't work in Terraform.

Is there a similar way to achieve the filtering goal in Terraform?

Thanks,

Comment: As someone who is not very familiar with JSONPath it's hard to guess what result you were hoping to get out of this. Could you please edit your question to include an example of what value you'd like the `site24x7IPs` output to have if the input is the JSON data you showed here?

Comment: What type are you expecting value to be? A `list(string)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the result:

```
output "australia_ip_with_quotes" {
  value = format("%q",element([for i in local.site24x7IPs.LocationDetails: i.external_ip if i.Place == "Australia"],0))
} 

output "australia_ip_without_quotes" {
  value = element([for i in local.site24x7IPs.LocationDetails: i.external_ip if i.Place == "Australia"],0)
} 

output "list" { 
  value = [for i in local.site24x7IPs.LocationDetails: i.external_ip if i.Place == "Australia"]
}
```

Outputs:

```
australia_ip_with_quotes = "103.91.166.0/24"
australia_ip_without_quotes = 103.91.166.0/24
list = [
  "103.91.166.0/24",
]
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for your multiple answers. The list is what I need. 
One extra thing, if external_ip is not in CIDR format, i.e. 170.78.75.87, I would like to add /32 behind it, what will be the best way?